# Javascript - return value from function

Tags: javascript

I have a JS library that is initialized like this:

```
$("#container").mylibrary({
    progressBarWidth: "480px",

    fileUploadProgress: function(progress) {
        // handle upload progress here
    },
    // etc. other callbacks and variables continue
)};
```

I want to change this so I can see if the user is on mobile and if so, return a different value for the progress bar width. How can I put a little function inline here, and return a value? I tried this, no luck:

```
    progressBarWidth: (function() {
         // do some math here
         r = '480px';   
         return r;
    }),
```

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: Huh? You mean, why didn't my code work? See the accepted answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined the function, but didn't execute it.  You can self-execute an anonymous function by simply adding parentheses after it:

```
progressBarWidth: (function() {
     // do some math here
     r = '480px';   
     return r;
})()
```

Comment: Thank you! Those parens... so small, yet so important. Dur.

Answer (score -1):

Like this ? (ugly... but i don't understand your question ;-) )

```
function myFunction() {
 var r = '480px';
 return r;
};
$("#container").mylibrary({
    progressBarWidth: myFunction(),
    fileUploadProgress: function(progress) {
        // handle upload progress here
    },
    // etc. other callbacks and variables continue
)};
```